# What is the difference between accumulator and combiner in collect?

Tags: java, java-stream

Why would the parallel stream use the combiner class, while the sequential stream would use the accumulator? Why does the parallel stream not use the accumulator?

```java
package Streams;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Collect
{
    public static class Debug
    {
        public static void log(Object ... objects)
        {
            for(Object object : objects) {
                System.out.println(object);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        parallel();
        Debug.log("---------------");
        sequential();
    }

    public static void parallel()
    {
        List<Integer> list = Stream.of(1,2,3,4)
                .parallel()
                .collect(
                        ArrayList::new,
                        (a,b)-> {
                            Debug.log("From accumulator",a,b);
                            a.add(b);
                        },
                        (a,b) -> {
                            Debug.log("From combiner",a,b);
                            a.addAll(b);
                        }
                );
    }

    public static void sequential()
    {
        List<Integer> list = Stream.of(1,2,3,4)
                .collect(
                        ArrayList::new,
                        (a,b)-> {
                            Debug.log("From accumulator",a,b);
                            a.add(b);
                        },
                        (a,b) -> {
                            Debug.log("From combiner",a,b);
                            a.addAll(b);
                        }
                );
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the code above:

```
From accumulator
[]
From accumulator
From accumulator
From accumulator
[]
[]
1
4
3
[]
2
From combiner
From combiner
[3]
[1]
[4]
[2]
From combiner
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
---------------
From accumulator
[]
1
From accumulator
[1]
2
From accumulator
[1, 2]
3
From accumulator
[1, 2, 3]
4
```

So again, why does the sequential stream use accumulator and the parallel stream the combiner? Can't the parallel stream use the accumulator?

Comment: Looks to me like your parallel uses both.

Comment: The `parallel` on stream makes the execution occur on different threads and that calls for the merge/combine to happen as a mandatory step, while for a sequential stream it is all under one thread, hence accumulator is sufficient at least, in this case, to perform the operation in pipeline. To understand that slightly better, you can change to `System.out.println(object + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());`

Comment: Accumulator adds one item, e.g. PartialResult + StreamItem. Combiner combines two partial results, e.g. PartialResult + PartialResult. Imagine your collector is making a List. An accumulator adds one item to a List: List + Item. A combiner merges two Lists: List + List

Answer (score 0):

The combiner's job seems to be to combine the different `List`-objects created for each thread (with `parallel`).

```java
    public static void parallel()
    {
        List<Integer> list = Stream.of(1,2,3,4)
                .parallel()
                .collect(
                        ArrayList::new,
                        (a,b)-> {
                            Debug.log("From accumulator",a,b);
                            a.add(b);
                        },
                        (a,b) -> {
                            Debug.log("From combiner",a,b);
                            a.addAll(b);
                        }
                );
    }
```

So in the example above, for 1,2,3,4 a new `ArrayList` is created for each element, because they run parallel on a different thread. So the combiner combines the 4 existing `ArrayLists` into one.

Comment: The phrase “seems to be” suggests that you are making guesswork, which raises the question why you don’t start with reading [the class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-), [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction), or [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#collect) instead.